# How to get Lubuntu to work on a PC from the year 2004?

Tags: lubuntu, system-installation

We have a hp pavilion v72 desktop computer from the year 2004. It had Windows XP running on it,  and we have been trying to install Linux on it.

After Ubuntu, we tried to install the 32 bit version of Lubuntu 13.10 from a disk image downloaded directly from the lubuntu.net web page, and it said it was successfully installed but after re-start it doesn't start the graphical user interface, eg. the screen remains black after the spash screen. The same happens, when we choose the option "Try Lubuntu". The computer's specifications meet the requirements of the lubuntu distribution. It has two graphic cards, one onboard, which can't be disabled in the bios and another one, which is configured as primary display adapter in the bios. The system can be booted to root shell and everythings appears to be fine, but when x-windows is started, the computer again hangs with an empty screen.

Do you have any suggestions, if trying another linux distribution (like xubuntu) might potentially solve the problem? Until recently, when we wiped the windows xp system, the computer worked perfectly well, so we don't assume, that the computer's hardware is defective.

Many thanks.

Anne

Comment: Also, since you are just installing a new system, I would suggest you to install the latest version which is 14.04 and it's an LTS so it has a minimum support period of 3 years from now. 13.10 just has a few months of support left (~3 months) so you would have to soon upgrade your OS if you go with 13.10 now.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to install Debian stable in case Ubuntu fails.

Also, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is reasonable option. But make sure you try to boot with both graphic cards to see if that is the case.

But, you didn't gave us much more details except that one. Maybe you can update your question with exact types of GPU you have?